# Корректно ли такое использование функции?

Tags: функции, php

Хочу вывести доступы

вот так:

```
function access($vid_access,$id_staff_access) {
 $query_access = mysql_query("SELECT access FROM access_staff WHERE id_staff = '$id_staff_access' and vid_access = '$vid_access'");
 $myrow_access = mysql_fetch_array($query_access);
 $access = $myrow_access['access'];
 echo $access;
}
```

применение

```
echo "доступ: ".access('view_lids',''.$userdata['id_staff'].'')."<br>"; 
echo "доступ: ".access('add_lids',''.$userdata['id_staff'].'')."<br>"; 
echo "доступ: ".access('give_lids',''.$userdata['id_staff'].'')."<br>";
```

у меня почему-то не выводит данные, хотя функция работает.

Comment: Вконце не echo, а return.
_____
И какой-то странный код.  
И непонятные '' перед  и после $userdata

    echo "доступ: ".access('view_lids',$userdata['id_staff'])."<br>";

Comment: не понял... 

попробовал убрать все лишнее

 function access_staff($vid_access) {

  $query_access = mysql_query("SELECT access FROM access_staff WHERE id_staff = '$userdata[id_staff]' and vid_access = '$vid_access'");
  $myrow_access = mysql_fetch_array($query_access);
  return $myrow_access['access'];
 }

echo "доступ: ".access_staff('view_lids')."<br>"; 
echo "доступ: ".access_staff('add_lids')."<br>"; 
echo "доступ: ".access_staff('give_lids')."<br>"; 

почему-то не работает =( точнее не выводит значение базы =(

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, много лишнего убрали, оставьте

    return $access = $myrow_access['access'];

А ещё данные выводить нужно вот так:

    foreach ($access as $access_staff) { echo $access_staff('view_lids'); }

Comment: Не работает, а почему так нельзя?

    echo "доступ: ".access_staff('view_lids')."<br>";